# wrong number of arguments (2 for 1), UsersController in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm making my way through [Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) and, while I have been able to troubleshoot a few errors on my own, this one from my trek through chapter 9 is sending me in circles.

My `views/users/index.html.erb`:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %> # Line flagged with error
    <li>
      <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
      <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

My Users helper:

```
module UsersHelper

  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 })
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

The error also flags another line of code that doesn't exist in my files; I guess it comes from the Ruby to HTML conversion?

```
delegate :to_xml, :to_yaml, :length, :collect, :map, :each, :all?, :include?, :to_ary, :join, to: :to_a
```

I've been scratching my head at this for almost two hours with no progress. All I know is that these errors go away when I replace the index page with simple text. Is this a problem with Gravatar? I really have no clue and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you pass to many args to the `gravatar_for` method.
Redefine it as following and you can use it as you do:

```
def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 })
  gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
  size = options[:size]
  gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
  image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
end
```

You have to read further to see how to redefine the method (it must be somewhere there).

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you. I really should have figured that I needed to add an option to `gravarar_for`. It's always the obvious solutions, right?

Comment: almost always :) please do not forget to accept the answer since it solved the issue (i think you would be able to accept it in like 5-10 mins)